# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS nginx after moving site to another server

Tags: nginx, error-handling, configuration

I moved the site (database, files and domain) from one server to another, but after the transfer, the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS appeared on the new server. This is my site config:

```
server {
server_name ad1.media  www.ad1.media 162.55.95.109;
 include snippets/phpmyadmin.conf;
    charset UTF-8;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;


                index index.php;
                root /home/ad1.media/ad1/public;


    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;


    location / {
#                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;            


    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
   #    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        



    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;


}


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ad1.media/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ad1.media/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot





}
server {
    if ($host = ad1.media) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


server_name ad1.media;
 listen   80 default_server;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = ad1.media) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name www.ad1.media; # managed by Certbot
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ad1.media/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ad1.media/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.ad1.media) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name www.ad1.media;
 listen   80 ;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I've tried multiple hours to solve it but I don't know why error is happening. I've seen that I need to remove this from config

```
if ($host = www.ad1.media) {
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

But it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browsers cache/use another browser? Permanent redirects are getting stored inside the browser, maybe your browser want to redirect you somewhere but thats not available anymore? Else you should be able to track the redirects you are receiving inside the devtools of your browser (in the network section), maybe these information will help.